# iPad - Update date format in a string by removing century

Tags: objective-c, ipad, date, nsstring, string-formatting

I currently have an NSString that contains 03/23/2011.

I would like to check to see if the string matches the XX/XX/XXXX format, and if so, remove the century from the year, ending up with XX/XX/XX, so in the example case, 03/23/11.

Should I do this by trying to get an NSDate from the string and setting the format that I want to get it back, or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would take a look at the NSDateFormatter, I think it holds the methods that you require.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDateFormatter

Comment: I see dateFromString and the it is "interpreted using the receiver’s current settings."  However, I don't see how to set a custom receiver setting to MM/DD/YYYY.

Comment: @John: `setDateFormat:`. You mentioned checking the string's format, though, so you might want to use `getObjectValue:forString:range:error:` rather than `dateFromString:` if there is a possibility that the string could be malformed. I believe that `dateFromString:` will give you the earliest possible valid date ("beginning of time", i.e.) if it chokes on parsing.

Comment: I am setting the date format with setDateFormat:[NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"MM/DD/YYYY" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]'  I try to get NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myString]'but data is staying null.

Comment: @John: Check your format string. Apple says you should use the [Unicode Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns). Uppercase-d, for example, is day of year, not day of month.

Comment: Thanks, changing it to MM/dd/yyyy worked, and it is now successfully converting to MM/dd/yy.